# How to get AJAX URL from a website using PHP/cURL

Tags: php, ajax, curl

My task is to get product list with prices from the link:
http://www.sanalmarket.com.tr/kweb/sclist/30011-tum-meyveler

Namely, I want to get this URL (or a better alternative):
http://www.sanalmarket.com.tr/kweb/getProductList.do?shopCategoryId=30011
(By the way, I cannot reach this URL on my own hook using PHP).

To get the cookie from original URL (first one) was simple:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init('http://www.sanalmarket.com.tr/kweb/sclist/30011-tum-meyveler/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
preg_match('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $result, $m);

parse_str($m[1], $cookies);
var_dump($cookies);
$cookie1 = reset($cookies);

echo $cookie1;

?>
```

Nevertheless, I cannot find a way to use this info to reach any JSON file or the URL which contains product info. I want to scrape the AJAX URL the website triggers to show the product list. Is there a way to do that?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for cookies, use your browser's devTools to monitor Network activity.

CTRL-J to display the console, then click on the Network tab and reload your page, you'll see this :

[image]

And there you go, use a simple `file_get_contents(url)` function and you're good.

Comment: Good to know that but since there is a need to reach this URL for every sub-category link, I should use a more convenient way like to get this URL by using PHP.

Comment: you should find the ajax call that gives you a category list, or scrape the categories from the html document.

Comment: if you get the html source, you'll see that there's all the links to all the categories in it. parse them to grab the categories id, then just use getProductList.do?shopCategoryId=XXX

Comment: Thanks for the answer sir. I didn't want to get the request by hand. I want to do that with PHP, because this website is the very little part of my work. I need to reach that request by code somehow.

Comment: I don't want to be stubborn, your answer is very clear and useful for me btw. :)